# Quadratic equation solver in TI-BASIC returns incorrect roots

Tags: math, quadratic, ti-basic

When I was in high school, I figured out how to program my [TI-84 Plus](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0001EMM0G) calculator to do quadratic equations for me. Like the goody-two-shoes I was, I deleted the program before the final exam. I am trying to recreate the program now, but it's not working well. Here's my code:

```
:Prompt A, B, C
:(-B+√(B²-4AC))/2A→Y
:(-B-√(B²-4AC))/2A→Z
:Disp Y
:Disp Z
```

(`→` corresponds to the <kbd>STO></kbd> (store) button on the calculator, which allows a user to set a value for a given letter variable.)

As far as I can tell, this *should* work. The math and the parentheses seem to be in order, the `Prompt` function works (after the program finishes, asking the calculator to print A, B, and C match the values stored from the last time the program was run).

When I ask it to calculate quadratic equations that I already know the answers to, it gives me funny numbers. Entering `A=1`, `B=-3`, `C=2`, which [should return *x*-intercept values of 1 and 2](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=0%3Dx%5E2-3x%2B2), returns 2 and 0 instead. The *x*-intercepts of 0=3x²-10x+7 [are 1 and 7/3](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=0%3D3x%5E2-10x%2B7), but the calculator returns 21 and 0. I can't reproduce it right now, but the this program has also returned some imaginary numbers where there shouldn't have been.

What's wrong with this code? The math works (inputting the second and third lines of code into the calculator to calculate, as opposed to lines of code in a program, after storing values in the variables does return the correct value), the `Prompt` and `Disp` functions work; what's wrong here?

Comment: FWIW, my code looks almost exactly like [the code here](http://www.instructables.com/id/Quadratic-Formula-for-the-TI-83-and-84/) except that their's displays a little more fancy. That code works, ostensibly.

Comment: I don't have a TI-83 emulator handy to test -- but can you try parenthesizing `(2A)`?

Comment: @duskwuff Huh. That seems to have done it. Thanks! ...do you want to write an answer, or shall I?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Order of operations strikes again. The expression

```
(-B+√(B²-4AC))/2A
```

is being parsed as

```
((-B+√(B²-4AC))/2)*A
```

Add parentheses to `/(2A)` to fix this.

Comment: How could that have caused the first example, as `A=1` should give the same result in both interpretations?

Comment: @LutzL Only thing I could see making that happen is if the division symbol was replaced with subtraction. That would give {2,0} for the first example.